# npgsql / PostgreSQL Very Slow Performance Over LAN

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, postgres-9.6

I am checking Postgresql Prepared Statements with npgsql.
Its working perfect on the same machine where Postgresql server is installed. 
With simple 100000 INSERT statements of random values on server (same machine)

Its inserting 100k records in 12.16 Seconds @ approx. 8224 records / second 
if Unprepared.
Its inserting 100k records in 7.76 Seconds @ approx. 12886 records / second
if Prepared statement
[image: Same machine with 127.0.0.1/172.16.16.33]
On client (Another machine in same LAN with same IP range and same configuration 8Gb RAM)

Its inserting 100k records in 89.36 Seconds @ approx. 1119 records / second 
if Unprepared.
Its inserting 100k records in 87.95 Seconds @ approx. 1137 records / second.
if Prepared statement.
[image: From Another Machine with ip 172.16.16.35]
This performance over the LAN is highly unacceptable. Please help.

I have already configured my postgresql server using https://www.pgconfig.org/#/tuning

Also disabled anti virus + firewall on both the computers.

The table is already UNLOGGED and does not have any constraint or index on it.

Postgresql version 9.6.12

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled=false; 
            button2.Enabled=false;
            button3.Enabled = false;
            lblUnprepared.Text = "Executing... Please Wait...!";
            lblUnprepared.Refresh();
            npgCmd.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE TBL_ETCBLACKLIST_TEST";
            npgCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            procInsertData();
        }

        private void procInsertData()
        {
            string strFileDownloadId = string.Empty;
            string strValues_0 = string.Empty;
            string strValues_1 = string.Empty;
            string strValues_2 = string.Empty;
            string strValues_3 = string.Empty;
            string strBlacklistFileNameWithoutExtension = string.Empty;

            DateTime strDateTime = DateTime.Now;

            DateTime strstarttime= DateTime.Now;


            objLog.Log(0, "Start Executing SQL");
            npgCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            npgCmd.Connection = npgConn;


            for (int i = 0; i <= lRows; i++)
            {
                //npgCmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
                //NpgsqlDataReader npgRD = null;

                strFileDownloadId = i.ToString();
                strValues_0 = RandomString(10, true) +  i;
                strValues_1 = RandomString(1, true);
                strValues_2 = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
                strValues_3 = RandomString(10, true);
                strBlacklistFileNameWithoutExtension = RandomString(10, true);

                strSQL = "INSERT INTO TBL_ETCBLACKLIST_TEST(ETCFileDownload_ID, ETC_Tag_ID, Tag_Status, Effective_Date, "
                   + " Reason_Code, CCHFile_ID, Create_DateTime, Last_Update_Date, CCHBank_ID) VALUES("
                   + strFileDownloadId + ", '" + strValues_0 + "', '" + strValues_1 + "', TO_TIMESTAMP('" + strValues_2 + "','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') "
                   + ", '" + strValues_3 + "', '" + strBlacklistFileNameWithoutExtension + "','" + DateTime.Now +"','" + DateTime.Now + "', 1 )";

                npgCmd.CommandText = strSQL;
              npgCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            DateTime strEndTime = DateTime.Now;
            var diffInSeconds = (strEndTime - strstarttime).TotalSeconds;
            var lRecPerSec = Math.Round(lRows / diffInSeconds);
            lblUnprepared.Text = string.Format("UnPrepared SQL Inserted {0} Records In {1} Seconds \n@{2} Records Per Second.", lRows, diffInSeconds, lRecPerSec);

            objLog.Log(0, "UnPrepeared SQL Processed in: " + diffInSeconds); 
            //npgCmd.Dispose();
            //MessageBox.Show(string.Format("UnPreapared Statement Processed in {0} Seconds.", diffInSeconds));
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button2.Enabled = true;
            button3.Enabled = true;

            //npgRD.Dispose();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strFileDownloadId = string.Empty;
            string strValues_0 = string.Empty;
            string strValues_1 = string.Empty;
            string strValues_2 = string.Empty;
            string strValues_3 = string.Empty;
            string strBlacklistFileNameWithoutExtension = string.Empty;

            DateTime strDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime strstarttime = DateTime.Now;

            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = false;
            button3.Enabled = false;

    npgCmd.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE TBL_ETCBLACKLIST_TEST";
            npgCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            objLog.Log(0, "Start Executing SQL");
            lblPrepared.Text = "Executing... Please Wait...!";
            lblPrepared.Refresh();

            strSQL = "INSERT INTO TBL_ETCBLACKLIST_TEST(ETCFileDownload_ID, ETC_Tag_ID, Tag_Status, Effective_Date, "
               + " Reason_Code, CCHFile_ID, Create_DateTime, Last_Update_Date, CCHBank_ID) VALUES("
               + "@Param1 , @Param2,@Param3,@Param4,@Param5,@Param6,@Param7,@Param8,@Param9)";

            npgCmd.CommandText = strSQL;
            npgCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            npgCmd.Connection = npgConn;

            npgCmd.Parameters.Add("@Param1", NpgsqlDbType.Numeric);

            npgCmd.Parameters.Add("@Param2", NpgsqlDbType.Text);
            npgCmd.Parameters.Add("@Param3", NpgsqlDbType.Text);
            npgCmd.Parameters.Add("@Param4", NpgsqlDbType.Date);
            npgCmd.Parameters.Add("@Param5", NpgsqlDbType.Text);
            npgCmd.Parameters.Add("@Param6", NpgsqlDbType.Text);
            npgCmd.Parameters.Add("@Param7", NpgsqlDbType.Date);
            npgCmd.Parameters.Add("@Param8", NpgsqlDbType.Date);
            npgCmd.Parameters.Add("@Param9", NpgsqlDbType.Numeric);
            npgCmd.Prepare();

            for (int i = 0; i <= lRows; i++)
            {
//                npgCmd = new NpgsqlCommand();

                strFileDownloadId = i.ToString();
                strValues_0 = RandomString(10, true) + i;
                strValues_1 = RandomString(1, true);
                strValues_2 = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
                strValues_3 = RandomString(10, true);
                strBlacklistFileNameWithoutExtension = RandomString(10, true);
                npgCmd.Parameters[0].Value = strFileDownloadId;
                npgCmd.Parameters[1].Value = strValues_0;
                npgCmd.Parameters[2].Value = strValues_1;
                npgCmd.Parameters[3].Value = strValues_2;
                npgCmd.Parameters[4].Value = strValues_3;
                npgCmd.Parameters[5].Value = strBlacklistFileNameWithoutExtension;
                npgCmd.Parameters[6].Value = DateTime.Now;
                npgCmd.Parameters[7].Value = DateTime.Now;
                npgCmd.Parameters[8].Value = 1;

                npgCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            DateTime strEndTime = DateTime.Now;

            var diffInSeconds = (strEndTime - strstarttime).TotalSeconds;
            var lRecPerSec = Math.Round(lRows / diffInSeconds);

            lblPrepared.Text = string.Format("Prepared SQL Inserted {0} Records In {1} Seconds \n@ {2} Records Per Second.", lRows, diffInSeconds, lRecPerSec);
            //MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Preapared SQL Processed in {0} Seconds.", diffInSeconds));
            objLog.Log(0, "Prepeared SQL Processed in: " + diffInSeconds);

            lblPrepared.Text = string.Format("Prepared SQL Inserted {0} Records In {1} Seconds \n@ {2} Records Per Second.", lRows, diffInSeconds, lRecPerSec);
            //MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Preapared SQL Processed in {0} Seconds.", diffInSeconds));
            objLog.Log(0, "Prepeared SQL Processed in: " + diffInSeconds);

            button1.Enabled = true;
            button2.Enabled = true;
            button3.Enabled = true;

            //Cant find npgsql.Unprepare();
            //npgCmd.Dispose();
            //npgRD.Dispose();
        }
```

postgresql.auto.conf is as below.

```
shared_buffers = '512MB'
effective_cache_size = '6GB'
work_mem = '82MB'
maintenance_work_mem = '512MB'
min_wal_size = '512MB'
max_wal_size = '2GB'
checkpoint_completion_target = '0.7'
wal_buffers = '16MB'
listen_addresses = '*'
max_connections = '100'
random_page_cost = '4.0'
logging_collector = 'on'
log_checkpoints = 'on'
log_connections = 'on'
log_disconnections = 'on'
log_lock_waits = 'on'
log_temp_files = '0'
lc_messages = 'C'
log_min_duration_statement = '10s'
log_autovacuum_min_duration = '0'
log_destination = 'stderr'
log_line_prefix = '%t [%p]: [%l-1] user=%u,db=%d,app=%a,client=%h '
```

Comment: Networking isn't magic. It takes a certain amount of time to transmit the information over a length of wire. Unless you can demonstrate that the time to transmit the insert statement and transmit the response is substantially less than one millisecond that is your slowdown.

Comment: Certain amount of time?
1137 records per second vs 12886 records per second.

Comment: It is not clear to me if you are doing separate inserts in separate transactions. If so could you do everything in one transaction or use bulk inserts?

Comment: Actually I get a file on a computer which is connected to the internet and then I have to run some 2.6M Inserts. 
I've done the part of COPY to local database but from there, I need to do the same Insert / Update to another machine connected in LAN.

Whatsoever, does postgres really runs so slow with everyone?

Comment: PostgreSQL is only slow when people do things like opening and closing connection for each statement separately or inserting each line in separate transaction etc. Which I am sure is not your case. I use a lot of ETL programs in GO and with bulk inserts and wrap into one huge transaction all is working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

As @felice-pollano wrote above, you probably want to check out [Npgsql's bulk copy support](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html), which allows you to insert large amount of data in a single roundtrip. It tends to be considerably more optimized than simply inserting.

If you perform a single roundtrip per SQL, then it makes sense for you to see a big perf degradation on the LAN compared to localhost. In the latter there's almost no latency, but in the former you're spending most of your time waiting for protocol messages to reach PostgreSQL and to come back.

Comment: Thanks for comments Shay! I was expecting you. Actually above is only a test application of my big application where I want to process 29M records in a table which will have a PK on it, to avoid duplicates or to update the records which are already inserted. So can I use UPSERT (INSERT INTO.. ON CONFLICT) in batch mode / bulk mode?

Answer (score 1):

If it slow down on LAN is probably due to LAN issues. By the way, massive inserts generally needs to be done with some sort of "bulk" or "batching" strategies, you probably take more time to talk each time to the database than actually executing db code.